# Zend ContextSwitch action helper for XML sets wrong Content-Type header

Tags: zend-framework, content-type, zend-framework-mvc, context-switch

Zend default ContextSwitch Action Helper for XML wrongly sets the Content-Type header to "application/xml" while the documentation claims it sets it to "test/xml".

Did anybody else bump into this. Is it a bug ? Thanks.

[zend Action helper documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a documentation bug.

From the code

```
'xml'  => array(
    'suffix'    => 'xml',
    'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml'),
)
```

**Update:** Bug filed - http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11406